# Fatal error : Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql

```php
<?php
class dblib {
    
    private $__conn;
    
    function connect(){
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "webtintuc";
        
        if (!$this->__conn){        
            try {
                $this->__conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                $this->__conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                die();
            }
        }
    }
    
    function dis_connect(){
        if ($this->__conn){
            $this->__conn = null;
        }
    }
    
    function insert($table, $data)
    {
        $this->connect();
        
        $field_list = '';
        $value_list = '';
        
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            $field_list .= ",$key";
            $value_list .= ",'".$value."'";
        }
        
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table. '('.trim($field_list, ',').') VALUES ('.trim($value_list, ',').')';
        $stmt = $this->__conn->prepare($sql);
        
        return $stmt->execute();
    }
    
    function update($table, $data, $where){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = '';
    
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            $sql .= "$key = '".$value."',";
        }
        
        
        $sql = 'UPDATE '.$table. ' SET '.trim($sql, ',').' WHERE '.$where;
        $stmt = $this->__conn->prepare($sql);
        
        return $stmt->execute();
    }
    
    function remove($table, $where){
        $this->connect();
        
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE $where";
        $stmt = $this->__conn->prepare($sql);
        
        return $stmt->execute();
    }
    
    
    function get_list($sql){
        
        $this->connect();
        
        $stmt = $this->__conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
        return $stmt->fetchALL();   
    }
    

    function get_row($sql){
        
        $this->connect();
        
        $stmt = $this->__conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        return $stmt->fetch();  
    }
    
    function get_row_number($sql){
        $this->connect();
        
        $stmt = $this->__conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
    }
}
?>



###post.php
<?php
$link = '';
$where = '';
if (isset($_GET["cat"])) {
    $cat = intval($_GET["cat"]);
    if ($cat != 0)
        $where = "WHERE category_id = $cat";
    $link = "cat=$cat&";
}

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM posts $where";
$total_records = $homelib->get_row_number($sql);

$limit = 3;

$current_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

$total_page = ceil($total_records / $limit);

if ($current_page > $total_page){
    $current_page = $total_page;
}
else if ($current_page < 1) {
    $current_page = 1;
}

$start = ($current_page - 1) * $limit;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts $where ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$data = $homelib->get_list($sql);

?>

<!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8">

          <h1 class="my-4">Siêu HOT
            <small>tin mới nhất</small>
          </h1>
          
          <?php 
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
            ?>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/<?php echo $data[$i]['image'];?>" height="300px" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $data[$i]['title'];?></h2>
                  <p class="card-text"><?php echo substr($data[$i]['content'], 0, 200).'...';?></p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Xem thêm &rarr;</a>
                </div>
              </div>
          <?php 
            }
          ?>


          <!-- Pagination -->
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
                <?php 
                if ($current_page > 1 && $total_page > 1){
                    echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="index.php?'.$link.'page='.($current_page-1).'">Prev</a></li>';
                }
                
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++) {
                    
                    if ($current_page == $i)
                        echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    else
                        echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="index.php?'.$link.'page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                }
                
                if ($current_page < $total_page && $total_page > 1){
                    echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="index.php?'.$link.'page='.($current_page+1).'">Next</a></li>';
                }
                
                ?>
           </ul>

        </div>
```

result:

> Fatal error
> : Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-3, 3' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\incs\class_db.php:100 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\incs\class_db.php(100): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\post.php(30): dblib->get_list('SELECT * FROM p...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\index.php(8): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\incs\class_db.php
> on line
> 100

Comment: The error is occurring because of the query passed to `get_list` from `post.php`. Please share that code too

Comment: i just added post.php.

Comment: i don't know where is the error? Can you fix it for me?

Comment: It seems `$total_page` is 0, so `$current_page` is also set to 0, and `$start` becomes `-3`. So it seems `$homelib->get_row_number($sql);` is returning 0.

Comment: so if i want to fix it, what should i do ?

Comment: ì $start = ($current_page + 1) * $limit; it's okay ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827398/php-fatal-error-uncaught-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: You need to figure out why `get_row_number` is returning `0` for your query

Answer (score 1):

The `limit` and `start` in an SQL query cannot be negative in any way. It is a number that is used for limiting the number of rows that should be returned by the SQL statement.

To be useful, the `limit` should always be an integer that is greater than zero. `start` should be any integer that is zero and up. It is refer to as the `offset`.

Your calculations are ending up producing a `start` that is set to `-3`. That will never work.

Make sure that you review your logic so that it does not produce a negative `$start` value.

You can quickly confirm my theory by calculating `$start` like this ...

```php
$start = max(0, ($current_page - 1) * $limit);
```

This will ensure that the value will be 0 if your formula returns a negative value.

Bear in mind that this is not a permanent solution. You need to properly figure out the way you are computer the value of the `$start` value.

Comment: tkanks you very much! have a good day !

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your issue, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer to help others out.

Comment: etou, i have one more quétion, can you help me ?

Comment: etou? Who are you referring to?

Comment: i add class_home.php with register.php, you can check for me ?

Comment: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'daoquangg97' for key 'username' in C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\incs\class_db.php:45 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\incs\class_db.php(45): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\incs\class_home.php(37): dblib->insert('user', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\register.php(14): homelib->register() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\webtintuc\incs\class_db.php on line 45

Comment: I'm from Japan. "etou" : it means oh ah. sorry for this trouble .

Comment: This new question should technically be another question on Stack Overflow. And the error means that you have a data with a primary key that that you are trying to insert twice in the DB.

Comment: tkanks you very much! have a good day !

Comment: You as well. I have learned some Japanese too. Thanks